# Row automatically clear data after the selector is selected

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have 2 selector on my grid (Req Employee ID and Actual Employee ID - both loads data from EPEmployee). `CommitChanges` of both fields are `True`. First, when I select the Req employee ID, this value will be loaded to Actual Employee ID field. It works. But when I select the Actual Employee ID, the value in Req employee ID is clear.

Here is my grid: https://uphinhnhanh.com/image/S6xTsQ

Here is `FieldUpdated` event which I use to load default value for Actual Employee ID:

```
    protected void PSMTExample_ReqEmployeeID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        var row = (PSMTExample)e.Row;
        if (row.ActualEmployeeID == null)
        {
            row.ActualEmployeeID = row.ReqEmployeeID;
        }
    }
```

Even if I commented this code, the problem still is there.

I would like the value of the first selector will be there when the value of the second selector is changed.

I don't know what I am missing. Please tell me why the first selector is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a need for CommitChanges="true" on the 2nd selector?  Try removing it, and also ensure that the grid marked as SyncPosition="true".

Comment: I have a description field for the selectors so I turn on ComitChanges to True to load  description field immediately after the selector is updated. I try to set CommitChanges to false on the 2nd selector, the 1st selector still is clear when I lose focus out of row. I also try to set SyncPostion to true but it doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps try adding IsKey=true to the data type attribute of one/both of the DAC fields involved to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Setting the column with DisplayMode="Text" should help to display the DescriptionField described for the PXSelector.

Comment: Considering IsKey attribute of DAC fields is a good idea. I tried to remove IsKey from one field of the related DAC and it works. Thanks a lot! @FarmerJohn